# heroku run fails - error connecting to dyno

Tags: heroku

When running simple bash

> heroku run bash

throws the following error:

> Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.3239
> !
> !    Error connecting to dyno, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process

The above link suggests to test connection to `rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com` on port 5000 using telnet

> telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000

A successful connection looks like:

> Trying 50.19.103.36...
>
> Connected to ec2-50-19-103-36.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
>
> Escape character is '^]'.

After running telnet I get similar output as the above.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The issue was in the Company Network I was connected. Some companies tend to block some ports `(in this case port 5000)` for security reasons. I tried running the same code after connecting to my hotspot and it worked like a charm.